# change git submodule clone url from ssh to https

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a git repo for which someone has already added the submodule and it seems they have made this submodule as git url rather than https url so as of now the submodule update tries to clone it ssh based git url.

I am trying to change now this submodule clone type to https based url and have modified the `.gitmodules` file where I have put the correct https url however the cloning or updating the submodule using command `git submodule update --init --recursive` still uses the ssh based url. Upon further examination it is observed that `config` file in `.git` folder of the main repo still has ssh url and I am not sure what process I should follow further to update locally as well as push the change to main repo for everyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After initial `git clone --recursive` or `git submodule update --init --recursive` URLs from `.gitmodules` copied to `.git/config` and changes in `.gitmodules` don't affect `.git/config`. You need to update URLs in `.git/config` using this command:

```
git submodule sync --recursive
```

See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-sync--recursive--ltpathgt82308203).

If you want to fix just one URL it could as simple as

```
cd <submodule_path>
git config submodule.<submodule_name>.url <new_URL>
cd <../back/to/the/superproject>
```

`<submodule_path>`, `<submodule_name>`, `<new_URL>`, `<../back/to/the/superproject>` are placeholders here.